# How do I specify a Perl 6 signature that encompasses everything I accept and excludes everything else?

Tags: signature, raku

My assumption in this question is that a signature that I specify completely describes everything that a method will accept. Apparently I'm wrong about that, but I'd like to get that anyway. If I don't specify it in the signature, I don't want other people to be able to provide it as an argument thinking it will do something.

I create a signature with a single positional parameter for a method, and I expect it to only accepta single positional argument. However, it also accepts named parameters without complaint:

```
class SomeClass {
    method something ( Int $n ) { 'Ran something' }
    }

put SomeClass.something: 137; # Ran something
put SomeClass.something: 137, :foo('bar'); # Ran something
```

But, if I define a method that takes a named parameter, that's called each time I define it second. Also, although I think I've said it requires a named paramter `foo`, it's not required and it still accepts named parameters that I did not specify:

```
class SomeClass {
    multi method something ( Int $n ) { 'Ran something' }
    multi method something ( Int $n, :$foo ) { "Ran $foo" }
    }

put SomeClass.something: 137;  # Ran
put SomeClass.something: 137, :foo('bar'); # Ran bar
put SomeClass.something: 137, :bar('foo'); # Ran
```

So, some questions:

- How do I specify a signature that encompasses everything I want to accept and excludes everything else?
- How do I force Perl 6 to choose the closest matching signature?
- In what order does Perl 6 decide to check the methods?

Comment: I think this is a problem in https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=130920 too

Comment: No, it is working as designed and implemented, although I agree this is a bit counter-intuitive (and I must admit it's taken me a long time to fully grok it and still am not sure this is more LTA than it should be).

Comment: Can you point to some documentation?

Answer (score 10):

You're touching on one of the things that is hardest to grasp about multi-*method* dispatch.  Most important thing to realize is that *every* `method` signature has an implicit `*%_` (aka a slurpy hash) if there isn't one specified.  This means that it will eat any non-specific named parameters.

```
class A {
    method a() { dd %_ }  # %_ exists even if not specifically specified
}
A.a(:foo)   # {:foo}
```

Second thing you need to realize, is that named parameters only act as tie-breakers.  So if there are multiple candidates that have the same matching set of positional parameters, MMD will use the first one that works (taking into account that all unexpected named parameters are slurped by `%_`):

```
class A {
    multi method a(:$foo) { say "foo" }
    multi method a(:$bar) { say "bar" }
}
A.a(:bar)    # foo
```

This seemingly unexpected result is caused by the fact that:

1. both candidates have the same number of positional parameters
2. the first candidate matches because `:$foo` is optional
3. and the `:bar` is eaten by the implicit `*%_`

To make it work more like you expect, you need to put the candidates that need to be tie-broken into the order you would like them to fire, and make any named parameters mandatory:

```
class A {
    multi method a(:$foo!) { say "foo" }
    multi method a(:$bar!) { say "bar" }
}
A.a(:bar)    # bar
```

If you have candidates taking multiple named parameters, it quickly becomes rather complex and you're possibly better off by just having a method that uses introspection of `%_`:

```
class A {
    method a() {
        if %_<foo> {
            say "foo"
        }
        elsif %_<bar> {
            say "bar"
        }
        else {
            die "None of the signatures matched"
        }
    }
}
A.a(:bar)    # bar
```

Hope this makes things clearer  :-)

Comment: If `(:$a, *%_)` and `(*%_)` are considered the same for the purposes of dispatching, why does it not throw an "Ambiguous call" error like it does for e.g. `($a, *@_)` vs `(*@_)`?

Comment: Is there documentation for this? Also, it looks to me like I have the methods in order that I'd want them to resolve, but that doesn't work for the call with no named parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Methods always come with an implicit `*%_` parameter, cf

```
say method {}.signature #=> (Mu $: *%_)
```

This is by design, with the idea that subclasses may pick out the arguments they like and then redispatch via `nextsame` et al (cf the [design docs](https://design.perl6.org/S12.html#Interface_Consistency) - not sure where or even if it's documented elsewhere).

There are several ways to reject undeclared named arguments, eg via a *where* clause

```
method m($positional, :$explicit, *% where !*) { ... }
```

or via an empty subsignature

```
method m($positional, :$explicit, *% ()) { ... }
```

When passing a non-declared argument, the former will fail with

```
Constraint type check failed in binding to parameter '<anon>'
```

and the latter with

```
Unexpected named argument '...' passed in sub-signature
```

I'll leave the exact semantics of multimethod dispatch for others to answer, but my heuristic rule of thumb is to make sure required named parameters are declared as such (ie the `!` is present) and to put the more general methods last.

Comment: Can you point to some documentation for this? And, perhaps, expand on why this design helps?

Comment: @briandfoy: The idea is that subclasses may pick out the arguments they like and then redispatch via `nextsame` et al, cf the [design docs](https://design.perl6.org/S12.html#Interface_Consistency). Construction via `submethod BUILD` works similarly. Personally, I'm not sure if this approach is pulling its weight: I've yet to make use of it in my own code, and the downside is that typos may be silently ignored

Answer (score 1):

I think `Int $n, :$foo` is more specific signature than `Int $n`. 
You can make `foo` mandatory

```
class SomeClass {
    multi method something ( Int $n, ) { "Ran something" }
    multi method something ( Int $n, :$foo! ) { "Ran $foo" }
}
```

or first signature more strict

```
class SomeClass {
    multi method something ( Int $n, *% where "foo" !~~ *) { "Ran something" }
    multi method something ( Int $n, :$foo ) { "Ran $foo" }
}
```